# Select rows in pandas where any of six column are not all zero

Tags: python, pandas

Here's what the pandas table look like:

[image]

As you can see the red marked rows have any of all six column values set to '0'. I want to select only non-red rows and filter these red ones out.

I can't seem to figure if there's in-built or, easy way to do it.

Comment: `df[df.eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)]`

Comment: `df[df.gt(0).any(1)]`?

Comment: The `df[df.eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)]` works as expected. Suppose if I had columns 'H', 'I', and 'J' as well. Is it possible to apply the same operation on any first '7' columns: 'A' to 'G' like above but ignore the presence of columns 'H', 'I', and 'J' completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean mask as suggested by @Ch3steR and use `.iloc` or `.loc` to select a subset of columns:

```
# Minimal sample
>>> df
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  3  2  # Drop
1  4  6  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  # Keep

# .iloc version: select the first 7 columns
>>> df[df.iloc[:, :7].eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)]
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1  4  6  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

# .loc version: select columns from A to G
>>> df[df.loc[:, 'A':'G'].eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)]
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1  4  6  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Step by Step:

```
# Is value equal to 0
>>> df.loc[:, 'A':'G'].eq(0)
       A      B      C     D     E     F     G
0  False   True   True  True  True  True  True
1  False  False  False  True  True  True  True


# Sum of boolean, if there are 3 True, the sum will be 3
# sum(1) <- 1 is for axis, the sum per row
>>> df.loc[:, 'A':'G'].eq(0).sum(1)
0    6  # 6 zeros
1    4  # 4 zeros
dtype: int64


# Are there less than 6 zeros ?
>>> df.loc[:, 'A':'G'].eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool


# If yes, I keep row else I drop it
>>> df[df.loc[:, 'A':'G'].eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)]
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1  4  6  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include information on how `.eq(0).sum(1).lt(6)` exactly works? it doesn't seem obvious to me yet but it works.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it helps.